# connect Laravel to a database on another IP

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-4, connection

I need my Laravel project to use a database that is on a virtual machine on another network.
I know there's two database configuration on

```
app/config
app/config/local
```

I'm using MySql, how should I configure the `database.php` file?

Right now is configured to my local:

```
'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'db_name',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => 'the_password',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
```

Comment: Do you need two access two different databases from the same installation or are we talking different environments here?

Comment: Just need one connection, and we are talking about different enviroments

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Can't you just change the host to the other ip? Or do you need help with setting up environments?

Comment: The problem is that when I set up the configuration, then I try to enter the webpage and this message is displayed to me:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (111)

I don't know if its problem of the configuration or the virtual machine

Comment: Do you have any MySQL client on the machine (running your application) installed so you could verify the connection?

Comment: Right now im on ubuntu, which client would you recommend me to use for testing the connection?

Comment: Nevermind. The error 111 means connection refused so you have to change something on your db server. Try changing `bind-address` in your MySQL config (usually `my.cnf`) to the public IP of the server. At the moment it is probably set to `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 1):

You should specify remote MySQL server host IP address in database.php configuration.

Also you need to make sure you have enable remote connection to your MySQL database (normaly most MySQL servers are restricted to connections only from localhost). For this purpose you will need to create new database user with the following command

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'IP' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

Where you put IP of the server where you laravel installation is located.

Also after that you must execute

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

And the you can connect to remote database.